# Connection Pooling with Access database

Tags: c#, ms-access, c#-4.0, connection-pooling

I have an application which reads data from an Access databse frequently, is there any way to use connection pooling?

My Open Databse method:-

```
private bool OpenDatabaseConnection(string databaseName)
{
    try
    {
        string connectionString = "Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; " +
            "Data Source = " + databaseName + ";";
        settingsDbConn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
        settingsDbConn.Open();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: I would suggest do not bother with connection pooling for the JET data base unless you are using remotely located db file, otherwise there is no significant overhead creating a new connection - in simplified version open a file under the hood.

Answer (score 7):

I concur with the comment of @sll but, to answer your question, then add this string to your connection string

`OLE DB Services=-1`

This will force the connection pooling with JET OleDB provider.
However test the performance of your app with and without this setting.
The difference should be negligible.
And, with this setting, rembember to ALWAYS return the connection to the connection pool closing it with con.Close or encapsulating your connection in a `using` statement.

Looking at your code above I will be very careful.

Comment: This worked! Without specifying the above property (OLE DB Services=-1) in the connection string, my C# application was taking 15 seconds for loading all data,  with opening/closing connection some 50 odd times. After adding this property, now it takes less than 1 second! Conclusion: By default, the connection pooling was not enabled. I am using Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0.

Answer (score 4):

These are the `connectionstring` attributes which can be used:

- All services (the default)
  `OLE DB Services = -1;`
- All services    except pooling
  `OLE DB Services = -2;`
- All services except    pooling and auto-enlistment
  `OLE DB Services = -4;`
- All services    except client cursor
  `OLE DB Services = -5;`
- All services except    client cursor and pooling
  `OLE DB Services = -6;`
- No services
  `OLE DB Services = 0;`

---

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/selvar/ole-db-resource-pooling

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you'll get any benefit from pooling for an access database. If performance is an issue, access is a poor choice.