# C# Microsoft Access Connection Pooling

Tags: c#, ms-access, connection-pooling

Intro: 
Using VS 2013, .Net 4
creating a library to connect/use a Microsoft Access database (part of 3rd party application - choice of database is not an option) to be used by our parent product.

Reason to pool: connections being made by multiple tablet PCs located throughout an industrial facility. Concerns regarding performance.

What do I need to add to the connection string, how do I initialize it?
When and how do I kill it?

Has anyone dealt with this before?

Why:
Answers I have found so far are vaugue

Comment: Have you looked at this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10012627/connection-pooling-with-access-database

Comment: only a partial answer... How/where do I initialize this so that it persists? Is there a way to test if a connection is open before running a command?  I'm thinking along the lines of a procedure I wrote in Access a while back for persisting a SQL Server connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a `System.Data.OleDb` connection you apparently don't need to do anything to enable connection pooling. According to the MSDN article [OLE DB, ODBC, and Oracle Connection Pooling (ADO.NET)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254502%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

> Connection Pooling for OleDb
>
> The .NET Framework Data Provider for OLE DB automatically pools connections using OLE DB session pooling.

For an application using `System.Data.Odbc` you need to enable connection pooling for the Access ODBC driver by double-clicking the "Microsoft Access Driver ..." name on the "Connection Pooling" tab of the ODBC Administrator control panel (odbcad32.exe) and choosing "Pool Connections to this driver"

[image: ConnectionPooling.png]

As stated in answers and comments to similar earlier questions (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10012627/2144390)), it's not too clear whether connection pooling will offer a significant benefit to an application that uses an Access database, but it is supported (ref: [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/169470), item #3) and it does seem to work based on what perfmon.exe displays for the "ODBC Connection Pooling" counters.

Answer (score 2):

Just to have it available somewhere to help people (and to expand upon the info provided by @Gord Thompson), and since the documentation seems to be misleading at best...

In my experience and environment, Access MDB and OLEDB + Jet 4.0 do not have connection pooling on by default, it is actually off unless you turn it on.  I'm pretty sure this is true for the ACE drivers as well, but I haven't recently done testing like I have for Jet.

Unlike ODBC (as far as I know), you can turn connection pooling on in the connection string with OLEDB.  In your connection string, add the following command to turn on pooling (again, this default pertains to Access and may not be true of other databases):  *OLE DB Services = -1;*

Here is a link to what different values are available and what they do
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/data/oledb/overriding-provider-service-defaults?view=msvc-170

Backup link in case MS does what MS does and kills doc links
https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.1?topic=tips-connection-pooling

Does connection pooling help with Access?
Short answer, yes, it definitely does.  To see the difference, brutalize Access by writing a loop that opens a connection, executes a query, then closes the connection and leave the "OLE DB SERVICES" command out, put a stopwatch in so you can time things and wrap it all up in the appropriate *USING* statements.   You will see that the open/close overhead is significant and you will also very likely see Access will start choking on that overhead on occasion throwing errors like:

> The database has been placed in a state by user 'Admin' on machine
> 'DESKTOP-XXXXXXX' that prevents it from being opened or locked.

It will also cause other applications connected to the database to choke with the same error occasionally.

Now turn on pooling in the connection string and you will see a HUGE performance increase and the occasional errors will go away.

This is not without drawback though.  Access and OLEDB have an issue where if one connection writes data, it may not be available to other connections for up to 5 seconds or, in some cases even longer due to not only a read buffer, but Jet's built in async write to disk process that runs on another thread.

In many cases with OLEDB, when you open/close the connection and query data, data written from another connection is available much more quickly as I believe the connection open process starts you with a fresh read buffer.   Connection pooling does exactly what you expect in this case and since the connection is already actually open, you are dealing with the existing connection buffer instead of starting clean and may have to wait up to 5 sec (or more) before data written by another connection is available.

Within the same app & pooling turned on, this may not be an issue because in the end, they'll likely (but probably not guaranteed to be) using the same connection anyways --- but if you have a different application (or same app on a different machine) needing data, you've got a problem.

So - depending on your environment and needs, connection pooling might be an asset or could be a liability.

I posted some additional info here on the buffer and ways to get around it
https://stackoverflow.com/a/74627552/2336839