# OleDbConnection Connection pooling

Tags: c#, ms-access, oledbconnection

I have around 10 repository classes to access different table data. All Repository classes can be initialized simultaneously. For example I mentioned a sample class below

```
public class table1DataRepository : Itable1DataRepository
{
    private OleDbConnection db;

    public table1DataRepository()
    {
      db = new OleDbConnection("Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = SampleDb.mdb");
    }

    public List<table1Data> GetAll()
    {
        var table1DataVal = db.Query<table1Data>("select * from table1Data");
        return table1DataVal.ToList();
    }

//Other methods here.............


}
```

Currently, in each and every tableRepository classes, I am opening new OleDbConnection to access the values and it is working fine.

Should I implement a Singleton pattern to share the connection or else connection will be automatically pooled?

Comment: you should inject the connection via constructor instead of having a connection per table

Comment: Using Singleton Pattern? A sample snapshot would be better.

Comment: Does the information in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33159619/2144390) help?