# Access database connection session state

Tags: c#, ms-access

What is *wrong* with this code ? how to *detect the session state*, code given below does not work as expected?

```
      OleDbCommand cmd4 = new OleDbCommand(sql4, conn4);

      if (conn4.State == ConnectionState.Open) {
        conn4.Close(); 
      } 

      conn4.Open();
```

Comment: You mean *connection* state? Don't use a global connection to begin with. Create the connection inside a `using` block only when needed

Comment: `code given below does not work as expected`. how it works? and what is the expected? And what is exactly the problem? Provide more info so other can help you.

Comment: idea of the code is to check whether the connection is already open , but even when the connection is open, it does not close the connection , trying to open it again throws an exception

Comment: Don't use a global connection. You don't need it. With a local database file, connection is instantaneous - the database is running inside your application after all. With remote database files you can [enable connection pooling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10012627/connection-pooling-with-access-database).

Comment: Did you debug the code? Does line `conn4.Close()` code gets executed?

Answer (score 0):

Connections implement `IDisposeable`. For Disposeables I have one rule:

"Never split up the creation and disposing of anything Disposeable. Create. Use. Dispose. All in the same piece of code, ideally using the using block."

There are some really rare exceptions like Logfiles, but a Database is not suiteable for any of those uses anyway (it has too many things that can go wrong on top of the issues files experience).